# Adding IP address to OpenVZ VPS (OpenVZ Web Panel)

Tags: ip, openvz

I apologise if I sound at all dumb. This is my first dedicated server having used a VPS for over a year and I'm trying to setup a VPS on this new server. I purchased a subnet from my hosting provider that I believe allows me 6 usable IP addresses:

`177.xx.xxx.201 - 177.xx.xxx.206`

The subnet address looks like this: `177.xx.xxx.200/29`. I've gone on my server and added them like it said on a wiki like so:

`ip addr add 177.**.***.201/29 dev eth0`

I done that for all six and now when I go to them in the browser they point to my server. The problem is, I'm using OpenVZ web panel to create VMs (http://code.google.com/p/ovz-web-panel/) so I created a VM and assigned one of those IPs to it. However when SSHing to that IP it SSH's to the dedicated server and not the VM. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenVZ is adding a new vmnet0 interface.

If those address are routed to your server IP address as a subnet You just have to enable routing in kernel.

If those address are on the same subnet as your server IP You have to create a bridge of this interfaces (venet0 and eth0).

I wrote that in polish but commands are the same :)

http://www.dobreprogramy.pl/okokok/How-To-Serwer-VPSow-na-OpenVZ-i-SolusVM-w-VMWare-Workstation-cz,37584.html

edit: Those address are in the same subnet as eth0. Don't add those address to eth0. Just create a bridge of eth0 and venet0.

edit2: Sorry, commands in my article are for CentOS :(

It's for Debian and Ubuntu: http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

You would have to install bridge-utils.

Comment: Hmm they are on a different subnet to the host server. But I have solved it. I had to go into `/etc/network/interfaces` and change the IP